# I can not install any application due to a repository update error

Tags: apt, updates

When I run `sudo apt-get update`, I receive this error message:

```
W: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-wine/ppa/ubuntu yakkety Release' does not have a Release file.  
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.  
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.  
E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-wine/ppa/ubuntu/dists/yakkety/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found  
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Due to this error I can not install any application, please help me in detail, I am very new to Linux.

Comment: Try to do read [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/768569/ubuntu-16-04-update-manager-error/784977) for more info.

Comment: how to remove that repository ? @cl-netbox

Comment: Ok I am waiting @cl-netbox

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Open **Software & Updates** -> **Other Software** -> mark the `wine` repository -> click on **Remove**.
In case that there is more than one entry for `wine`, remove the other one (Source Code) as well.

[image]

In the screenshot you see my repositories and in this example the `LXD` repo would get removed.
When you run `sudo apt update` or `sudo apt-get update` now, it will succeed without an error.

**Update** addressing your comment that you are not able to install `vlc` packages ... even though not asked in the original question, the packages are available in the Ubuntu universe repository.

```
$ apt policy vlc
vlc:
  Installed: 2.2.4-4ubuntu0.16.10.1
  Candidate: 2.2.4-4ubuntu0.16.10.1
  Version table:
 *** 2.2.4-4ubuntu0.16.10.1 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu yakkety-updates/universe amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     2.2.4-4 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu yakkety/universe amd64 Packages
```

Make sure that all official Ubuntu repositories are enabled as it's shown in the screenshot below :

[image]

After having enabled all repositories and running `sudo apt update`, you are able to install `vlc`.

Comment: Ok fine and nice answer by the way but my problem is still unsolved as i try to  install vlc by using this command 
sudo apt-get install vlc browser-plugin-vlc
I got these errors 
E: Unable to locate package vlc
E: Unable to locate package browser-plugin-vlc

Comment: @MoeedAzhar your question did not mention VLC. cl-netbox gave an excellent, understandable answer to the question you asked. That *you asked the wrong question* is not relevant. You should accept this answer, and open a new question with your REAL question.